# How do I re-install/re-access GRUB so that I can regain access to my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub

A few days ago, I made an exact clone of my hard drive to my newly bought SSD. On the SSD, my Ubuntu partition is still present, and I safely assumed that all the data on there is still intact. Before cloning, my laptop would always boot into GRUB before proceeding to Windows 10 or Ubuntu. However, after installing the SSD, my laptop no longer boots into GRUB -- it just goes straight to Windows 10. How do I reaccess (or reinstall, if necessary) GRUB so that I can boot into Ubuntu again?

If it matters, I'm using a Dell laptop with a SanDisk Ultra 1 terabyte hard drive. Windows 10 (Pro) is installed on a 790 GB partition, and Ubuntu is installed on a 140 GB partition located right next to it. [Here's an image of my setup in case I'm not describing it very well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQUo.jpg)

Comment: You can use EasyBCD to add Ubuntu to Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add GRUB as a boot option and select it as default. This is done by creating a new boot option in the BIOS pointing to the grup.efi file on the EFI partition. Unfortunately, I am not able to give more specific instructions because the process varies from motherboard to motherboard.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!